# Prove that $[N, G']=1$ when $N$ is a nilpotent subgroup of a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried evaluating an arbitrary generator of $[N,G']$, but I can't show it equal to $1$ that way.

Working with examples such as when $G=S_3$ and $N=A_3$, then $[N,G']=[A_3,A_3]=1$ holds, but I don't have an idea about how to prove this is true in general.

Comment: My first guess is that the claim is false. Let $G$ be the group of invertible upper triangular 3x3 matrices. $G'$ would then consist of the subgroup with 1s on the diagonal. That subgroup is nilpotent, so let $N=G'$. Then $[N,G']$ consists of the upper triangular matrices with 1s on the diagonal, 0s next to the diagonal, but the (1,3) entry arbitrary, no? Check the list of assumptions, please.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I thought the subgroup $G'$ in your example is $Z(G)$, in which case $[Z(G),Z(G)]=1$?

Comment: And I checked again to see I'm missing something, but all that's known is that $N$ is a nilpotent subgroup of $G$.

Comment: The statement is false in $S_3$ with $N$ a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false as stated. Elaborating on the example from my comment.

Let $G$ be the group of invertible upper-triangular $3\times3$ matrices over, say, a finite field $K$ (to make $G$ finite in case it matters) with at least three elements (to avoid certain degenerate possibilities). Then with
$$
D=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&c\end{array}\right),\quad
X_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),\quad
X_2=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
we get
$$
[D,X_1]=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&a/b-1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),\quad
[D,X_2]=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&b/c-1\\0&0&1\end{array}\right).
$$
From this we easily see that
$$
G'=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&d&e\\0&1&f\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)
\,\bigg\vert\,d,e,f\in K\right\}.
$$
If we select $N=G'$, then $N$ is nilpotent, because $N'$ only contains matrices with $d=f=0$, and $[N',N]$ is trivial.

But $[G',N]$ is not trivial because, for example,
$$
[X_1,X_2]=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)\neq 1_G.
$$

---

Of course, there are simpler counterexamples (see Derek Holt's comment). The groups of (unipotent) triangular matrices just have these nice derived series (resp. lower central series).

---

The assumption $|K|>2$ is needed above, because when $K=\Bbb{F}_2$ we have $a/b=1$ for all $a,b\in K^*$.